# Cpu support for the asus PRIME A520M-A II CSM

Tags: processor, motherboard, compatibility, ryzen

Im thinking on buy several motherboards  [A520M-A II CSM](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/CSM/PRIME-A520M-A-II-CSM/) , but I don't know if these are able to support the Ryzen 5 5600G and the Ryzen 7 5700G. In the cpu list support only appear the

```
Ryzen 5 5600GE (3.4GHz,35W,L3:16M,6C)   
Ryzen 7 5700GE (3.2GHz,35W,L3:16M,8C)
```

this are, AFAIK, not the same models than the intended to install.

And Im concerning this since this motherboard does not have a method to update the bios without cpu, in the event this aren't supported. Perhaps I'm too pesky, since it is supposed to support the 5xxx but *after* it has been updated to  AGESA 1.2.0.3b, and the board seems to be released with a prior version.

I hope someone could give me a hint, if this processor are supported or confirm if it can be updated without cpu (the button in the back panel or inside the board).

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most times, you choose your cpu and feature set, and then go here to ask which motherboard is best... To make things even weirder, those Ryzen 5xxxGE processors are validated since a non-existing BIOS.......

The ASUS prime B550M-A WIFI II has a similar feature set as the A520, but it will surely support those cpu's. If it fits in your budget, try that one.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking  what to do but since this is a pc for job I opted by a Gigabyte  Gigabyte Micro ATX A520M DS3H , this at least has the flashback button. The detail of the BIOS number...yeahh it says after 1804, but I see the first is a 2400 or something like these. So in the end it has support already or not at all.